# Is $A \times B$ a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> So, I am trying to prove if $A\times B$ is a function; where
>
> $$:  \to  $$ and $ = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $ = \{2, 4, 5\}$.

I am able to do this with for example $\{(1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 5), (4, 4)\}$.

As far as I understand one way to do this is with matrix multiplication, but since the sets don't have an equal amount of elements I am unable to do that.

Is there another way to prove if this is a function or not?

Comment: Keep in mind that the cross-product $A \times B = \{(a, b) \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$.  If you list all the ordered pairs, the answer should be clear.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So the ordered pairs will be: {(1,2), (1,4), (1,5), (2,2), (2,4), (2,5), (3,2), (3,4), (3,5), (4,2), (4,4), (4,5)} ? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That is correct.   If $f$ is a function, how many output values may each input value have?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig for f to be a function it can have a maximum of 1 output value, therefore this is not a valid function?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $B$ has more than one element, the set $A \times B$ will never define a function. For example, take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{x,y\}$. Then $A \times B = \{(1,x),(1,y),(2,x),(2,y)\}$. So, the element $1$ is mapped to two distinct values $x$ and $y$! More generally, because $B$ has at least two elements, any element of $A$ is mapped to at least two distinct values in $B$.

So, the moral point is that the relations on $A \times B$ that are functions are generally proper subsets of $A \times B$, unless $|B|=1$ where $|B|$ denotes the number of elements of $B$.

An interesting result about the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ for the case when $A$ and $B$ are finite sets is the following theorem

> **Theorem:** If $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, there are $n^m$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

Note that the number of relations that can be defined on $A \times B$ is very large. In fact, we have $2^{m\times n}$ relations on $A\times B$ because $|A\times B|=|A||B|=m\times n$. But only $n^m$ of these relations will turn out to satisfy the condition for being a function from $A$ to $B$.

For example, if $m=2$ and $n=5$, there will be $2^{10}=1024$ relations on $A \times B$, while only $5^2=25$ of these relations turn out to be functions!

Answer (score 0):

Take a subset A1 of A s.t. |A1| = |B|. Then f(A1) is a bijective function.

Map the rest of the elements of A without A1 to B under f. Now A is surjective onto B.